# Could we have an option to enter submit a line in chat, rather than start a new line?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat, mobile-web

I've got SE chat set up in a docked window in mobile mode in windows 8, and use it fairly regularly on an Android phone. In both cases, hitting the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key starts a new line. It would make sense to have a user selectable option to have it submit the line (so you didn't have to hide your on screen keyboard every line), and have <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> start a new line instead - as it does on regular chat.

Could we have this fixed please?

It was just pointed out to me that [this may be a duplicate of this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128570/enter-to-send-in-mobile-chat) - I've made a *slight* change to make this a distinct question. It still stands that there's lots of cases where the screen is large enough to avoid this issue, for example on a tablet, or where the lower bandwidth usage and rescaling of the mobile client is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently with the ["new" mobile chat (Introduced in early 2016),](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273727/test-the-new-mobile-chat) this issue is fixed. Hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> sends, hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> creates a newline.

This is pretty much what I wanted,