# Test the new mobile chat!

Tags: discussion, chat, mobile-web, announcements

> Update: As of February 23, 2016, the new mobile version is the default. If you've tested the new version before this date, nothing will change for you (even if you've disabled the new version since, in which case it will continue to be disabled).

Remember 2010, when smartphones looked like this?

[image: photo of a candlestick phone]

Back then, we created a mobile version of chat, so that people could use the bare minimum of features on those and similar phones.

Well waddayaknow, suddenly it's 2016, smartphones for some reason now look like this:

[image: photo of a Google cardboard]

– and the "bare minimum" seems a little underwhelming.

So we made something (special credit goes to [Paweł](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/225016/pawe%C5%82) and [Chris](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/13/chris-jester-young)).

Above all else, the most important thing is that you can finally **interact with arbitrary messages**:

[image: screenshot of the new mobile chat with a selected message and various options]

– you can reply, edit, get the permalink, star, etc. (assuming relevant permissions, of course). Just click<sup>1</sup> a message to interact with it. If you can't, because the whole message consists of just a link (and you don't want to click the link, you want to select the message), then click somewhere around it and if necessary use the up/down arrows to move the selection to the correct message.

Only the rooms list and the live chat itself currently use this new version, and we consider this whole thing a beta.

Oh, and in this new version, you can submit new messages by just pressing Enter.

Give it a spin, and as always, [post issues here on Meta](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=chat+mobile-web).

If you want to stick with the old version, you'll find a checkbox on the "prefs" tab of your chat profile with which you can disable the new mobile version.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>I know it's not really "clicking" on a phone, but you know what I mean.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup>You can check or uncheck that box on your desktop computer – it only sets the preference that *when* you look at the chat on your phone, *then* you want or don't want to see the new version. If you're active on more than one of the three chat sites (chat.meta.se, chat.se, and chat.so), then you have to change the setting on each of them.</sub>

Comment: With the new UI, will the chat API be published in the docs anytime soon?

Comment: By the way, what about bug that appears *only* on desktop browser using mobile view? Should I post it too? (It's kind of weird for the bug only occurs on desktop browser, but not mobile browser... and using mobile view on desktop)

Comment: What's the current status of moderator / room-owner stuff with the new theme?

Comment: [So, status complete?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160597/150515)

Comment: @Andrew think you can post such a bug, worst case it will be declined.

Comment: [Bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273870/239016).

Comment: [Another status-completed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126874/230261)? :D

Answer (score 31):

Fantastic news!

Predictably, this does not work at all with [Chatsey](https://stackapps.com/questions/4659/chatsey-an-android-app-for-se-chat), and since it is no longer required due to the fab new UI, I'll just take it down.

Comment: It's going to be weird to not have Chatsey installed anymore

Comment: I can't use the new chat because of [accessibility issues](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273752/162102) -- they baked in smaller fonts and the page doesn't zoom.  As long as old chat is available and this problem isn't fixed, I'll have a use for ChatSEy.  I really hope they can do something about that, as I assume that at some point old chat will cease to be available and I'd hate to be shut out when that happens.  I rely on my phone to keep an eye on chat.