# XKCD onebox broken in new mobile chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, mobile-web, onebox

Since the interface is not [beta anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273727/test-the-new-mobile-chat), let's open a bug that's bothered me for a while :-)

The xkcd onebox isn't responsive at all. Half of the comic will be too far on the right.

Probably a small css fix!

Comment: Screenshots plz

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unacceptable. Fixed with high priority.

Comment: All hail quick fixes! Thanks.

Comment: Wish all SE was now in beta test so that all bugs would be fixed so quickly. :-D