# Mobile chat header displaced

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, design, mobile-web

In the [new (beta) design for mobile chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273727/test-the-new-mobile-chat), not all chatroom titles appear to fit, and are pushed down onto the chatroom content:

[image: chatroom with misplaced header circled]

I circled the title (*Full Blue Moon (aka The Blue Room)*), which is white and not positioned on the header. Since this is a moderator room, I blurred out most content.

In other rooms with shorter titles the title stays in the header:

[image: Python chatroom with correctly placed title]

Comment: I will take a look at this, thanks for reporting!

Comment: @Pawel Can you tweak your profile here a bit so you get your diamond. I'm highly confused if at first sight ordinary users fix the SE software...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This, together with a few other potential issues with the header bar layout, is fixed now.