# New mobile chat: please make the "last message" info bigger or zoomable

Tags: feature-request, chat, mobile-web, accessibility

I'm really excited about the [new mobile interface for chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273727/162102).  Unfortunately, there's one thing that's causing me problems right out of the gate: itty bitty text combined with an inability to zoom.

I use the rooms list to see which of my subscribed rooms have had recent activity that I should go take a look at.  (Especially on a phone, I don't tend to just keep 20 chat tabs open.)  The most important things on the rooms list, therefore, are: room name, how long ago the last message was, and who posted it.  Before this change, I could read all that clearly.

With the new interface, the latter two -- time and author -- are much harder to see: smaller font and not offset from the rest of the text there the way they were.  I cannot read this on my phone, and the page does not respond to a zoom gesture.

Side-by-side comparison:

[image: screen shots with red freehand circles]

That might not look like a big deal on a desktop computer or tablet, but on a <5" phone screen that change in size and layout makes a difference.  For me it moves from "just readable" to "no longer readable".

If I soldier past that and enter a room it looks like the font there might also be a bit smaller than it was, though I can't tell for sure.  So far, I'm having a worse chat experience than before (when I just used ChatSEy if I actually wanted to *talk* in a room from my phone), so I'm going to change back.

Could you please do something to help those of us who can't read the text at the sizes you've chosen?  I especially expected zoom to work on a *web page*, like it does on other SE pages like my network profile and inbox.  (I know that zoom often doesn't work in apps.)

**Update:** It's been most of a year and somebody was going to look at it, so I tried again.  No change; still can't read that tiny font.  The information obviously *can* fit with a bigger font because it *did*, and the site change that enabled this broke ChatSEy.  So chatting from my phone is a pretty terrible experience (no direct replies, for one thing), and as a moderator I sometimes need to do that.

Comment: Excellent.  I'm not the only one.

Comment: Agree with this. Paweł is looking at it.

Comment: @balpha [this Paweł](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/225016/pawe%C5%82) I assume? Why no diamond? :)

Comment: @balpha any update from Pawel?

Comment: @balpha any updates on new-mobile-chat font sizes?