# New Mobile chat: link color and regular text color are too similar

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, design, mobile-web

Let me start by saying that I *love* the [new Mobile UI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273727/test-the-new-mobile-chat) for chat.

There is one minor problem though:

[image: screenshot]

The colors of links and regular text are just too similar. I can barely tell them apart in this screenshot (32" monitor, max. contrast), and not at all on my phone (6", mediocre contrast).

Could the difference in styles please become a little more obvious?

Comment: That's a bug, it's picking the wrong link color.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The link color is supposed to be the same one as in the desktop version, but in the new mobile version it used the wrong LESS varible. Fixed now.