# The New Mobile View has been out of beta since 2016. Do we still need an option to disable or enable it?

Tags: feature-request, chat, mobile-web

While looking up something completely unrelated, I came across the mention of a New Mobile View (beta)

[image]

I was overjoyed. Overwhelmed even. Then I remembered I'd been using it for years and it had come out of beta in *2016*

I do realise that chat's nowhere on the roadmap for updates, but it seems a little incongruous to have an option that's useless for the last 7 years, predates most of the current staff *and* could confuse a new user looking for other things.

As such, when time and convenience permits, could we have this removed, and with it the false hope and crushing disappointment that it brings?

Comment: I've seen complaints posted here about people finding the new mobile UI too animated for their eyes and preferring the old one because it doesn't have as many animations. It should definitely be kept. That said, since it is out of beta, the settings page should no longer phrase it as being in beta - it'd be nice if you'd find the link where they announced that it was fully released.

Comment: Also, the old UI is still used on mobile transcript pages.

Comment: [Test the new mobile chat!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273727/test-the-new-mobile-chat) - everything's in one place

Comment: The mobile ui is literally missing some features, until it’s improved to include them… not having a way to use the non-mobile view would be problematic for those who use the missing features

Comment: no no. The other option is the *old* mobile UI.