# Dealing with "difficult" usernames in targeted comments

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, display-names, comment-replies, unicode

Once in a while you wish to address a comment to someone in particular, so you type `@` and then you pause ... because the username is [l̕aͨŵƦȆ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝ƞCͭ̏ȇ ƇhƐȓ0nè](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661872/laec-h0ne) or [Ωmega](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1215106/mega).

Short of using copy-paste to get their username right (which is even more cumbersome on a mobile device), is there another way around this? In a few cases I've noticed that the system will attempt to "promote" a comment to a reply, but I'm not sure if that's very reliable.

Should user names at least start with a normal letter?

**Update**

The auto-complete feature seems to normalize Zalgo'ish usernames, so typing the letter L will trigger the suggestions as expected; this is of course knowing that the name actually spells "lawrence", which may not always be obvious.

Knowing the way of the symbol ninja would surely help to type Ω using only the elbows as well, but not everyone is blessed with the same keyboard layout.

**Suggestion**

It would be nice to have a reply feature like this:

> [image: reply feature proposal]

When `↳ reply` is clicked, it will automatically populate the comment box with `@username` pre-filled in.

**Additional notes**

To clarify, I'm not suggesting to put the "reply" on *all comments*, as proposed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74778/add-reply-link-to-comment-that-pre-populates-comment-box-with-username), because in most cases the owner of a post is already notified of a new comment; this would strictly be to effect cross-commenter communication.

Comment: If you're on a mac, just try Alting some keys. You might get the character :).

Comment: Your keyboard doesn't have a `l̕` key ?!

Comment: It's not fun even on a Mac.  Autocomplete garbles the hell out of the name into a tiny space.

Comment: Using usernames like that is their way of muting comment notifications.  If they wanted comments, they'd use a name people would know how to type.

Comment: Just don't talk to these people.

Comment: It would be nice if you could just click on the username in the comments to start a new reply with the appropriate @ syntax pre-populated.

Comment: That screenshots mockup needs a nice, red, freehand circle. And an arrow.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on what characters can appear in a username? What about full-width exclamation marks?

Comment: @J.Steen I suck at freehand drawing, so a elliptical 2px stroke is the end-result =p

Comment: @KerrekSB Display names can contain letters, digits, spaces, apostrophes, and dashes. "Letter" in that case includes a lot of unicode goodness though.

Comment: @Jack Sucking at freehand drawing is kind of the point. ;) Nice job though. Highlights do help. I had trouble spotting that the first time around. I did, eventually, and then I suggested the circle!

Comment: ޤo͛ͫƦR̘̝̙ͤ͂̾̆Y̷̙ ̒ͩͣ̅̓͒̀ͤ̂͂̄̊҉̶̝̗̦͡͠   ƒoȓ  қiÇK͠1n͘G҉   ̛​͟uP̯͍̭ ̒ͩͣ̅̓͒̀ͤ̂͂̄̊҉̶̝̗̦͡͠    Á  s҉7i͡N̐kͫ͏. ;p

Comment: @Lawrence No worries, I was gonna write the question before anyway, but your display name was added for kicks :)

Comment: @hims hey and what if Jack has a time machine? ;-)

Comment: @Jack answer already in the [**answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168155/155556) and so it should stay...

Comment: There are also legitimate use cases to have usernames start with non-latin characters; e.g. users from countries with different alphabets; i.e. it's not only Zalgo (unless he has some role in the Babel myth...).

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I've been meaning to make this change for a while, so this was a good nudge to finally do it:

From the next build on, if a comment thread contains a comment by a user whose name starts with a non-ASCII letter, then just typing `@` will bring the tab completer up with that name:

[image: screen shot of the tab completer offering a name that does not start with an ASCII letter]

If all reply candidates start with "normal" letters (or numbers), then the tab completer behavior is unchanged; it will only start suggesting once you've typed an additional letter.

If there are two or more reply candidates starting with a non-ASCII letter, they will be listed side by side after just typing `@`.

Note that this will *not* offer you l̕aͨŵƦȆ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝ƞCͭ̏ȇ ƇhƐȓ0nè – that name starts with a nice and friendly lowercase "L".

Regarding your "click to reply" idea: That has been [declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74778/add-reply-link-to-comment-that-pre-populates-comment-box-with-username) previously. I'm still considering your discussion/request to be completed because of the above change.

If you really want reply links, I've [create a user script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2051/reply-links-on-comments) a long time ago that gives you just that. With the advent of the tab completer, I have actually stopped using it myself, but it should still work.

Comment: Thanks! Though, I wouldn't want to have "reply" links *everywhere*, because in many cases they would not be necessary; e.g. comments of the poster wouldn't need it. I've added that clarification in the question as well.

Comment: Awesome, I always wondered how to deal with those names as copying was a big headache!

Comment: This is really great, but it does not work in chat :(. Feature request is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185317/222340).

Comment: What about mobile?

Comment: @balpha that script you linked to does not work.  I know this thread is more than 8 years old so I am not unduly disappointed.  Still, if you figure out how to update/reinvigorate it, I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 13):

I followed your link to Lawrence's profile and from there to an answer of his. I clicked Add Comment and typed `@l` whereupon the autocomplete offered me his whole name.

For Ωmega I couldn't find a letter to type that triggered the autocomplete - I expect copy and paste would work.

Comment: Then maybe, at least the first letter should be '''normal''' (I know the word is inappropriate but I think you understand what I mean, _common_ … maybe?)

Comment: Are you looking for "ASCII"?

Comment: @cpast it's not as restrictive as that. The first letter of l̕aͨŵƦȆ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝ƞCͭ̏ȇ ƇhƐȓ0nè is not plain text (there's some sort of diacritic over the l) but typing an `l` works for autocomplete.

Comment: Just as another data point, typing Ω, which is available under ⌥-Z on an Apple US keyboard (and I'm sure there's some way to type it on other systems, even if it's awkward), brings up the autocompletion for Ωmega.

Comment: @JoshCaswell if I copy/paste Ω, and start typing @Ω into an answer where Ωmega participated this doesn't bring up the autocompletion for me (but it should)(I'm on Windows).

Comment: @JeromeJ: Copy-paste also works for me. Make sure you are doing this on a post where it is not the case that [Ωmega is the post owner and only one other person has commented](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation). I used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307575/ for testing.

Comment: @KateGregory: Although it appears that way, it is really a plain "l", lowercase "L". Full name is:  `l` `\`` `a` `ͨ` `ŵ` `Ʀ` `Ȇ` `̴` `̟` `̟` `͙` `̞` `ͩ` `͌` `͝` `ƞ` `C` `ͭ` `̏` `ȇ` `Ƈ` `h` `Ɛ` `ȓ` `0` `n` `è` (had to wrap each char in code backticks to get individual characters to appear here.)

Comment: The autocomplete may sort of work, but does the actual reply-mechanism? Will it ping the user or is there a mismatch when the @username is, fundamentally, different from the actual username?

Comment: @user159834 not really, the backtick is part of the l. Try pasting the name `l̕aͨŵƦȆ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝ƞCͭ̏ȇ ƇhƐȓ0nè` in an input box, putting the text caret in the beginning of it, then shift-right-arrow once, then copy with ctrl+c. You'll copy the backtick too: `l̕`.