# Will my username prevent me from getting responses

Tags: discussion, display-names, comment-replies

My username is the same as my [Stack Overflow one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1063093/phadaphunk) but upside down.

When someone wants to respond to me by pressing `@` then starts to type my name, will he be able to type `k` and get the first letter of `ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd` right? Or will he have to type in the upsidedown `ʞ` or even copy/paste my name?

Comment: When you type `@` your name is already being suggested, *because* you use non-ASCII characters at the start.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Take this as exemple. When I pressed `@` nothing was suggested because you and oded responded. I had to type `m` to get your name suggested.

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd <-- just needed to type the @ to see that.

Comment: So you can end up having more comments addressed to you than if you had an ASCII user name!

Comment: If I get a headache from standing on my head, I'm holding you responsible.

Comment: I wonder what happens when there are **two** users with funky name? @George care to change your display name so I can test? ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I call Dibs on that upcomming bug !

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd And be saddled with gobbledegook for 30 days? There are some things I won't do, even for science. ;)

Comment: @George Come on! Just here on Meta... pretty please? ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I'll do it with my sockpuppet. After all... its its purpose

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd you mean your ʇǝddndʞɔos! :D

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Exactly

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd [horray](http://i.stack.imgur.com/41HXx.png)! :P

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Clever solution !

Comment: @GeorgeCummins You can change it a few times before getting a 30 day block.

Comment: I tested it with my screen turned upside down and it also works.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Now try finding me in the Users section without copy pasting and with your keyboard only. ;)

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd yup you're well hidden from view... until they add option to sort by display name! :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After a [recent change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168155/152859), the autocomplete feature suggests your name *immediately* when typing just the `@` at symbol:

[image: auto-complete phunky names]

*because* your name starts with a non-ASCII character.

If I then add charaters, other auto-completes are suggested instead:

[image: auto-complete Oded]

Comment: Ooh that's a nice feature. Thanks :)

Comment: Took the liberty to link to the relevant feature request hope you don't mind. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Nope, thanks!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd argh, I was just about to mention that answer! Four minutes of my life, wasted to MSO searching!