# Order users by username

Tags: feature-request, search, users-page

Right now, when displaying all the users, the default order is by reputation.

I suggest we add a way to order the users by username too. This would be useful when searching for a non-ASCII names that we can't type in the search bar without copy-pasting stuff. Something useful for non-ASCII names was done [in the comment section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168155/174490).

> [image]

[Sha Wiz Dow Ard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/152859/sha-wiz-dow-ard) came up with this idea in the [comments here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183129/will-my-username-prevent-me-from-getting-responses).

Comment: I suggest we order by user name, Skeet first. That way, the list will remain familiar.

Comment: It will also make it easier to find users with inappropriate display names.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yeah you may add that to the question.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi There should actually be a permanent link to his profil next to the site's logo.