# Top Users page clips long tag names

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, design, users-page

I just noticed [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users). Hey! I'm there! But that's beside the point.

The point is that Nick Craver is there too. Nick seems to like really long tag names, so his profile shows up like this:

[image]

<sub><sup>Akk! Diamonds everywhere!</sup></sub>

It seems that the page is optimized for only two lines of tags per user. One tag per line means three lines. Three lines means that Nick's reputation (tag) is cut in half.

Let's not cut Nick's rep (tag) in half on the Users page, no?

Comment: It has been this way for a very long time, now it is a feature.  If you keep bringing it up then you do run the risk of Atwood+ coming to your house and bashing you with a giant W.

Comment: @Uphill That's better than getting bludgeoned to death with a giant S, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're my tags, and I'm fine with them being cut off - that third one wasn't important anyway.

Seriously though, this is an edge case we won't spend time styling each site on.  Instead, we could spend time on other changes we could make to `/users` to make it more useful, that's just a nasty rumor though. Maybe.

Comment: Maybe option to [sort by username](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183143/152859)? Pretty please? :)

Comment: But if you [got a possible fix on a purple plate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/235182/152859) won't you just take it?

Comment: @ShadowWizard they're intentionally cut off since there are some *massively* long tags, we don't plan on changing that.

Comment: Fair enough @Nick, thanks.