# Tags getting cut in Top Users Page

Tags: bug, tags, design, users

When there are too many tags associated with a single user, they got cut. It's a UI Issue.

[image: Example: most people have three tags visible, but Varun Verma's third tag is mostly obscured and unreadable]

Comment: The page was designed for smaller named tags like `[php]`, `[c#]` and `[jquery]`.

Comment: ok. But now are we handling such issues? I think we can handle it with simple css changes.

Comment: [bad news](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188798/top-users-page-clips-long-tag-names/188805?noredirect=1#comment773337_188805).

Answer (score 3):

@Varun's suggestion is wonderful, but what if there is more tags? Then I suggest the following style for `.user-tags`, Which will create a wonderful scrollable box with tags...

## 1. ...with small dotted border:

#### Quick demo<sup>1</sup>

```
javascript:for(var i=0;i<document.getElementsByClassName("user-tags").length;i++){var el=document.getElementsByClassName("user-tags")[i].style;el.height="26px";el.overflow="auto";el.border="dotted 2px";el.borderRadius="4px";}
```

#### CSS

```
.user-tags{
   height:26px;
   overflow:auto;
   border:dotted 2px;
   border-radius:4px;
}
```

## 2. ...with more elegant dotted border:

#### Quick demo

```
javascript:for(var i=0;i<document.getElementsByClassName("user-tags").length;i++){var el=document.getElementsByClassName("user-tags")[i].style;el.height="26px";el.overflow="auto";el.border="dotted 1px";el.borderRadius="4px";}
```

#### CSS

```
.user-tags{
   height:26px;
   overflow:auto;
   border:dotted 1px;
   border-radius:3px;
}
```

## 3. ...without a border:

#### Quick demo

```
javascript:for(var i=0;i<document.getElementsByClassName("user-tags").length;i++){var el=document.getElementsByClassName("user-tags")[i].style;el.height="26px";el.overflow="auto";}
```

#### CSS

```
.user-tags{
   height:26px;
   overflow:auto;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> - paste in address bar and hit <kbd>enter</kbd> ;-)

Note that running javascript from address bar should be enabled in your browser.

Comment: Appreciated :) .

Comment: @VarunVerma Love it? ;-)

Comment: It's very cool (may be without border) ! :)

Comment: @VarunVerma Check an edit ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Just an suggestion. I changed the height to auto of that highlighted div and the problem got solved. May be we can implement it in production.
Attached is the snapshot.[image]
Please consider.