# Addressing users with non-standard first letter in chat

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, autocomplete, ping

Not too long ago, there was a nice new feature implemented for comment replies to users whose username starts with a non-alphanumeric character; namely, that typing `@` is sufficient to bring up the autocompletion. The relevant thread is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168155/222340).

Recently, I have been in a chatroom with a user whose username has above properties; however, when I typed the `@` in chat to try and ping them, no autocompletion was triggered.

I suspect that it was simply overlooked to update the chat ping functionality to reflect the change that was made to comment replies.

So my request is simple:

> Please activate the `@`-triggered autocompletion for usernames which start with non-alphanumeric characters in chat as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's been a while, but this is now finally in chat as well:

[image: screenshot of the chat input box containing "Hey @" and the autcompleter showing the username ɥʇǝS]

Comment: Now we can ping Seth when he hangs upside-down in the Tavern.