# Reply for a chat message using keyboard only

Tags: feature-request, chat, keyboard-shortcuts

Chat has a pretty well `@nickname` autocomplete system, however, it is not possible to select a parent message without mouse:

[image]

Wouldn't it be great if a parent message for a particular user could be selected without loosing input area focus?

[image]

I've made a simple script as a proof of concept ([GitHub](https://github.com/soon/StackOverflowExtensions/tree/master/chat/message_parents))

Comment: That's really nice :)

Comment: Nice script!! You should post that on StackApps so others can see and use it! :D

Comment: Maybe this could be implemented whenever this is: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268351/260841...?

Comment: One word: Neat...