# How to mention user in comments with non-ascii name?

Tags: support, display-names, comment-replies

Many times I wanted to post a reply in comments to some people with a names, that contain some characters, that I don't have on my keyboard. Auto-completion with @ doesn't always work, so I'm confused - how can I mention those people?

Even if write his name - how can I be sure, that the name is correct? That he will be notified?

Comment: I'd just copy and paste the name, but usually it autocompletes on 0 letters (I think editors are the exception to this)

Comment: You can notify only two users in a single comment

Comment: Also, it doesn't autocomplete post owners, because they are notified automatically.

Comment: @Bala I want to notify only single person per comment.

Comment: If the first character of their name is on your keyboard just use the autocomplete which will appear after you type `@[letter here]`. If you're on mobile, you might need to switch to full site mode to enable this. If the first letter itself is non-ASCII then the name should appear when just typing `@`. (pretty recent change)

Comment: @RichardTingle just tried - auto-complete works on first letter after symbol @. So, if the name start with something unprintable - no way to auto-complete.

Comment: If the first letter is "unusual" autocomplete starts at the "@"

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd no it will not appear to me when I type @

Comment: @RalZarek [not accurate](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oxB5s.png). It will appear when there's at least one other user who commented too.

Comment: @abyss.7 Thats really odd, I've replied to an all upsidedown letters username and it autocompleted from 0

Comment: @Bala because all names here start with ordinary characters.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Didn't know about this new feature - was it ever announced somehow? - Will try next time. By the way, what characters are "ordinary"?

Comment: @abyss.7 alphabets are ordinary

Comment: @abyss.7 yes, [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168155/152859).

Comment: @Bala Do you mean "english alphabets" or what? I suggest, that any "unusual" character belongs to some alphabet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[As of February 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168155/152859), when a user name starts with an "unusual"<sup>1</sup> letter they will be available as autocomplete as soon as the @ is inserted

> [image]

<sup>1</sup>non-ASCII letter