# How do some users make their usernames show upsidedown and things like that?

Tags: support, display-names

It seems that some users have unusual characters or HTML in their usernames or something. But the field in the Profile only accepts a very short entry. How are they doing this?

Comment: Unicode characters. There are also some sites on the internet specifically for this purpose. The downside is they're not pingable on Android. That's why I changed back to saner characters long ago.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253326/usernames-with-weird-unicode-characters-that-are-annoying-and-adversely-affect-f

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't much to it - they misuse some Unicode characters that **look** like some English letters upside down.

There are even websites that will generate the string for you:

http://www.whatsmyip.org/upside-down-text-flipper/

Comment: ˙oɟuı ǝɥʇ ɹoɟ sʞuɐɥʇ ¡ʇɐǝɹƃ ,ʎǝH - I'll still upvote instead of downvoting, though!